# DataTemplate only shows Canvas for the last record

Tags: wpf, grid, datatemplate

I'm using the following DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="platform_resources">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Viewbox Width="30" Height="30" ToolTip="Network Domain Count" Stretch="Uniform">
           <ContentControl  DataContext="{Binding}" Focusable="False" Content="{DynamicResource appbar_server}" />
                </Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Margin="0,7,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=workload_count}"/>
                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
                <Viewbox Width="30" Height="30" ToolTip="Logical Network Count" Stretch="Uniform">
                    <ContentControl Focusable="False" Content="{DynamicResource appbar_network_server_connecting}" />
                </Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Margin="0,7,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=vlan_count}"/>
                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
                <Viewbox Width="30" Height="30" ToolTip="Network Domain Count" Stretch="Uniform">
           <ContentControl Focusable="False" Content="{DynamicResource appbar_network}" />
      </Viewbox>

     <TextBlock Margin="0,7,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=networkdomain_count}"/>

   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The template displays all the relevant data with separators but only shows the images on the last record. It's leaves spaces where the images are supposed to be, but no images.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you add `x:Shared="False"` property to your resources.

Example:

```
<Canvas x:Key="appbar_server" x:Shared="False">
   <!-- ... -->
</Canvas>
```

Comment: It produces the same result. See my code below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you probably defined some `Image`s (e.g `appbar_server`) in your resources and trying to display them in multiple items. But `Image` is a `Visual` and in `WPF` each `Visual` can only have one parent. So when your items are being generated, each item steals the `Image` from the previous one until the last item finally gets it.

**Solution:**

Unlike `Image`, `BitmapImage` is not a `Visual` and thus can be set multiple times as the source of different items. So instead of defining `Image`s in your `Resources`, define `BitmapImage`s:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="appbar_server" UriSource="C:\...\appbar_server.png"/>
    ....
```

And then instead of `ContentControl`s create `Image` instances in your `DataTemplate` to present them:

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Viewbox Width="30" Height="30" ToolTip="Network Domain Count" Stretch="Uniform">
                        <Image  Focusable="False" Source="{DynamicResource appbar_server}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,7,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=workload_count}"/>
                    ...
```

***Update:**

> The image is captured in a canvas which seems to be needing some
>   special wrapper to make this work.

In that case, you should define a `DataTemplate` for each `Canvas` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="appbar_3d_3ds">
        <Canvas  Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
            <Path Width="32" Height="40" Canvas.Left="23" Canvas.Top="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 27,18L 23,26L 33,30L 24,38L 33,46L 23,50L 27,58L 45,58L 55,38L 45,18L 27,18 Z "/>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
    ....
```

And then create `ContentPresenter` Instances in your `ItemTemplate` with their `ContentTemplate` set to your pre-defined data templates (e.g. `appbar_3d_3ds`).

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Viewbox Width="30" Height="30" ToolTip="Network Domain Count" Stretch="Uniform">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource appbar_3d_3ds}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,7,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=workload_count}"/>
                    ....
```

Comment: Seems I'm missing something. The image is captured in a canvas which seems to be needing some special wrapper to make this work.

I get the following error now:
"'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception.' Line number '16' and line position '48'."

Comment: This is what the canvas looks like:     <Canvas x:Key="appbar_3d_3ds" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="32" Height="40" Canvas.Left="23" Canvas.Top="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 27,18L 23,26L 33,30L 24,38L 33,46L 23,50L 27,58L 45,58L 55,38L 45,18L 27,18 Z "/>
    </Canvas>